# Remote Debugging Azure App Service with API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

Is there a setting necessary to be enabled for APIM to forward remote debugging calls to its associated app service? When I portqry, the port is reported as Filtered, not Listening.

Comment: Using VS 2022 and trying to attach the debugger via the publishing host, I am getting: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'xxx.xxx.com:4024'.   I have made sure my firewall is allowing the IDE and debugger apps thru.

Comment: Looking at my reply above to you, all of sudden '4024' jumped out. It is not a valid port per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022 Port 4026 should be for VS 2022.

Comment: Changing the App Service "Remote Visual Studio version" specification to VS 2019 didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to the problem. First, download the latest publishing profile for the app service and open it. With the project loaded, select Debug > Attach to Process. Use the destinationAppUrl in the profile for the Connection target. Append the url with ":4024" and tap "Enter". That will start the connecting to the cloud debugger for the app service. A login dialog should appear. Use the
first userName and userPWD values to fill the dialog. When entering the userName, prefix it with a backslash so your local domain is not applied. Select the Attach button.

From my experience to date, multiple attempts may be necessary. When that fails, try disabling Debugging in the app service and re-enabling with saves in between. Also restarting the app service might assist.